# How to zoom out webpage in Firefox OS Packaged WebApp

Tags: firefox, web-applications, zooming

I am developing a packaged webapp that redirects the user to a website. The website doesn't have a mobile interface and we want it to be zoomed out and fitted as per the page width.

When we are testing in simulator(firefox OS 1.3 to firefox OS 2.0), we are getting the page zoomed in to the top right corner of the page. Is this only specific to the simulator or this will happen on the actual device as well? Is there a way to prevent that from happening and getting the page zoomed out for initial loading time?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl + scroll wheel down` or `ctrl and -` ?

Comment: The question is not how to zoom out manually, but how to make sure that when the page will load it will be zoomed out automatically as per the page width

Answer (score 0):

Try to press `CTRL and -` or `CTRL + mousewheel down` and see if that zooms it out.